# Code seems to stop xml layout from showing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

The problem is that I have an Android app that doesn't seem to show the xml layout when I put this while loop into the class file. The loop is as follows:

```
while(!clicked){
        button_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player= MediaPlayer.create(GameActivity.this, R.raw.a);
                player.start();
                clicked = true;
                letterTapped = 0;

            }
        });
    }
```

The whole project works completely fine without it so I'm pretty sure that there must be something wrong with the loop that I am overlooking.
If you want me to put any other bits of code up here I will be more than happy to.

Comment: This is not how you use `Listeners`. Remove the `while` loop and it should work.

Comment: Ah right okay, so could you tell me how to properly repeat listening until a press and then stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **stop** listening as soon as the button is pressed, you can use this code:

```
button_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        player= MediaPlayer.create(GameActivity.this, R.raw.a);
        player.start();
        letterTapped = 0;

        // Ignore further clicks
        button_a.setOnClickListener(null);

        // Disable button so the user knows that he can't click again
        button_a.setEnabled(false); 
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason when I use that code it asks to force close when I start the activity. 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity - caused by java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Looks like `button_a` is not initialized. Do you have something like `button_a = (Button) findViewById(...)` **above** the code I posted?

Comment: Yeah, where should it be in the class? I've tried it outside of all functions, inside that function, inside onCreate and inside onStart and none of them seemed to work

Comment: If I declare it in the class at the top it just crashes, and if I declare it anywhere else it says that I need to declare it final

Comment: It should be in `onCreate` directly above the code that I posted. Write `final Button button_a = (Button) findViewById(...)`.